# How to create a "weight" field when sampling a population in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I am sampling a population and I'd like to know if there is a straightforward way to generate a column called "weight" that indicates the sample weight in the sampled data.

Here is my code.

## I create the population that is to be sampled

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Age':[18,20,20,56,56,57,60]})

print(df)
   Age
0   18
1   20
2   20
3   56
4   56
5   57
6   60
```

## I take a 30% random sample of that population

```
sampleData = df.sample(frac=0.3)
print(sampleData)

   Age
6   60
5   57
```

What I would like to know is whether it's possible to generate a field called "weight" that indicates the sample weight (without having to manually calculate the weight). So, I'd like my sample data to look like:

```
   Age  Weight
6   60   3.333
5   57   3.333
```

Comment: Can you tell how the weights are computed?

Comment: Basically - weight accordance to importance. You can specify for example - the older is the guy -the more weight he have.

Comment: The weight is calculated as 1/frac . So, with larger datasets, if i factor the sample back up I can replicate the population by using the weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `assign()` method and inside it use `round()` method:-

```
frac=0.3
sampleData=df.sample(frac=frac).assign(Weight=round(1/frac,3))
```

Now if you print `sampleData` you will get your desired output:-

```
    Age     Weight
4   56      3.333
2   20      3.333
```

Comment: If this answer helped you then try considering acceping this answer....Thanks :)